# Class inheritance and class casting

Tags: java, class, inheritance, selenium, casting

I'm writing some test scripts in Selenium that need to apply across multiple browser types. My idea is to create a base browser object with multiple sub-classes specific to each browser type, e.g. Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc. Each subclass contains the browser-specific details, but common functional definitions hide the implementation details.

I'm trying to avoid a single class loaded down with if-then-else structures to cover all the driver-specific details, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it work.

Example:

```
public class Browser {
    public Browser() {
        //does stuff...
    }

    public void launch(String url) {
        //launches browser from WebDriver object
    }

    public void close () {
        //closes browser from WebDriver object
    }
}

public class Browser_Chrome() extends Browser {
    public Browser_Chrome() {
        super();
        // WebDriver specifics...
    }
}

public class Browser_Firefox() extends Browser {
    public Browser_Firefox() {
        super();
        // WebDriver specifics...
    }
}


public class webApp extends Browser {
    public webAbb() {
        super();
    }
}
```

I only want to have a single test script that doesn't care what browser is currently running. I'm fairly new to Java, so perhaps there is a better way to do this? I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Why is `webApp` extending `Browser`, and not `Chrome` and `Firefox`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn't Selenium already support this?

Comment: What browser specific details you need? Also why not to code only for `Webdriver` and assign required browser instance to it?

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I screwed that up so badly. My original architecture DOES have Browser_Chrome and Browser_Firefox extending the base Browser class. I apologize for the confusion and will edit the original posting to clear it up.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Selenium does support virtually any browser, but you have to use browser-specific driver objects, and each has slightly different configuration characteristics. I don't want to have to deal with such issues in my test scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood you want your web app to communicate with browser class regardless of its type (chrome,firefox,ie). if that's the issue then the `Browser_Chrome` and the `Browser_Firefox` should extend the `Browser` class and override the implementation of the `lunch` and `close` functions in each child class if the `Browser` class.

For the `wabapp` should have a variable of type `Browser` and call lunch or close if needed.

like the following

```
public abstract class Browser { // make it abstract because you cant make a browser that's not ch
    public Browser() {
        //does stuff...
    }

    public void launch(String url) {
        //launches browser from WebDriver object
    }

    public void close () {
        //closes browser from WebDriver object
    }
}

public class Browser_Chrome extends Browser {
    public Browser_Chrome() {
        super();
        // WebDriver specifics...
    }
}

public class Browser_Firefox extends Browser {
    public Browser_Firefox() {
        super();
        // WebDriver specifics...
    }
}


public class webApp {
    private Browser borwser; 
    public webAbb(Browser borwser) {
        super();
        this.borwser= borwser;
    }

    public void lunchBrowser(){
       borwser.lunch();
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked very well. Its what I was trying to get to, but implemented poorly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could write an abstract class with methods that you want each browser to do which each browser would overwrite for their own specific use.

So maybe something like this:

```
public abstract Browser { 
    abstract void launch(String url);
    abstract void close();
}

public class Chrome extends Browser {
    public Chrome() {
        ...
    }        

    @override
    public void launch(String url) {
        ...
    }
    @override
    public void close() {
        ...
    }
    //then add class specific methods to make those 2 methods function as you like.
}
```